# React JS video.js not able to play on safari IOS showing images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, http-live-streaming, video.js

I have a react component with a video js library. when I try to play `Paatra_Movie.m3u8` format video it is working on a standalone component with just video js. but when I integrate it into my main component which contains video quality and subtitle features this video is not playing on the safari browser but works fine on chrome/firefox.

Need to send cookies in the header to verify for the video. `withCredentials` is working fine, cookies are also going to request and the response is also OK

it is just showing a black screen but when updating the seek bar it is showing the images of the video

no errors or warnings in the console

any one faced the same issue on the safari please help, what can be the issue for this

```
`<video ref={videoRef} poster={contentDetails?.s3_backdrop} 
 autoPlay={false} className={'video-js'} onProgress={handleProgress} disablePictureInPicture={true} preload={"auto"} ></video>`
```

data returning to video ref

```
`data: {
      src: data?.playback[0]?.playback_url,
      type:'application/x-mpegURL',
      cookies: data?.playback[0]?.cookies,
      withCredentials: true, // enable sending cookies with request
      playsInline : true // safari
    },`
```

player ref

```
     `const player = videojs(videoRef.current, {
    html5: {
      hls: {
        withCredentials: availableProvider?.name == PROVIDERS.NAMMAFLIX ? true : false,
      }
    },
    controlBar: {
      pictureInPictureToggle: false,
    },
  })`
```

Comment: Please may you add a text-based [mcve] showing the issue?

Comment: added the code for the same

Comment: Related?  https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/4354